# How can i dismiss modalViewController without leaving current view?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

My application is view based app. First view is login view. After login view i have MainMenuCcontroller which has a tabBarController:

```
 @interface RunnoMainMenuController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
 }
```

From login view controller, i am going to MainMenuController using this line of code:

```
 [self presentModalViewController:mainMenu animated:YES];
```

this controller has 4 tabs. Now i need to do some stuff in viewWillAppear of a tabBarItem. viewWillAppear is not called when i tap a tabBarItem. I have a button in one of those tabBarItem's view which pops up a table view controller using presentModalViewController. This tableView uses dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES to disappear it. When i pop up this tableview and dismiss it then viewWillAppear of every tabBarItem works fine. If i will dismiss modalViewController in MainMenuController then it will again go back to login view. How can i dismiss modalViewController without leaving current view or any other solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to consider how your views are presented. The tab bar controller should always be the window's root view controller. From the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the
>   root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar
>   interface should never be installed as a child of another view
>   controller.

Rather than present your login view as the root view and the tab bar as a modal view controller, try it the other way round. The tab bar controller as root, with the login view as presented as a modal view controller from the view controller of whichever tab is shown initially. Dismissing this will then reveal the tab bar controller.